# Prove that secure authenticated encryption system composed with itself is secure

Tags: authenticated-encryption, security-definition, integrity

Suppose $(E,D)$ provides authenticated encryption with key space $K$. Define $(E',D')$ with key space $K^2$ as follows:
$$
E'((k_1,k_2),m) = E(k_2,E(k_1,m)) \\
D'((k_1,k_2),c) = \begin{cases}
D(k_1,E(k_2,c)): & D(k_2,c) \ne \bot \\
\bot & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
How to construct a ciphertext integrity attacker on $(E,D)$ given one on $(E',D')$?

I get stuck at matching the keys. I know the attacker on $(E',D')$ can give me a ciphertext which decrypts successfully. However, under what key? In the definition of ciphertext integrity the key is chosen at random by the challenger before the attacker submits its allowed queries. Now I'm supposed to construct an attacker on $(E,D)$ which has a non-negligible advantage against the challenger which starts its algorithm by choosing a random key from $K$. I suppose there's some nuance in the definitions that eludes me, allowing to somehow relate this key to the key from $K^2$ for $(E',D')$.

Comment: https://www.isiweb.ee.ethz.ch/archive/massey_pub/pdf/BI434.pdf is likely of interest. Any cascade of ciphers with independent keys is at least as secure as the innermost ($E(k_{1},m)$ here).